# make reposync ignore /etc/yum.conf?

Tags: yum, repository

Is there a way to make reposync ignore /etc/yum.conf ?

When i use `reposync --config=/my/path/to/alternative/inputrepo.conf` it's still picking up repositories for consideration inside `/etc/yum.repos.d`

My alternative/inputrepo.conf just looks like:

```
[varnish]
name=varnish
baseurl=http://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-3.0/el6/x86_64/
```

...but reposync still picks up the google-chome repo, which is only in /etc/yum.repos.d/ and complains about varnish being defined twice.

This is a problem for me because some of the mirrors i want to sync are also present on the system in /etc/yum.repos.d/, but with different baseurls.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue in 2023, the only solution I have is to rename your repos so there is no name overlap. Instead of `[varnish]` use something like `[varnish-3]`. Not a very elegant solution.

Comment: This fix may help:

https://serverfault.com/a/586499/110096

Set `distroverpkg` to the OS major version, and possibly the `cachedir` and `persistdir`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your alternate `yum.conf` you need to set `reposdir` to something else so it won't look in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

I put my repo definitions for reposync in `/etc/reposync.repos.d` so the line to add to the `yum.conf` you're using for reposync would look like this:

```
reposdir=/etc/reposync.repos.d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
% reposync -p [destdir] --repoid=varnish
```

This option will sync repo varnish repo to your local repo to whatever directory you provide.

```
% reposync -p [destdir] -n --repoid=varnish
```

Will sync only the newest files for subsequent syncs.

Answer (score -1):

Check out `yum --disablerepo="*" ...` and similar flags. Read the `yum` manpage.

Comment: I thought of this, but how does that help ? both repos have the same name. In my case 'varnish'. I can disable both, then will reposync use the ones from my file regardless ? -- i'll go try it.

Comment: no joy. aside from all else, --disablerepo disables for the following yum operation, not a reposync one.